# How do I not include part of a regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, string

I'm pretty new to using regexes and I can figure out how I would go about extracted a specific number from a string.

Suppose the string was any amount of whitespace or random text and somewhere within it is this, "Value: $1000.00."

In order to retrieve that value I am currently using this:

```
string value = Convert.ToString(Regex.Match(BodyContent, @"Value:[ \t]*\$?\d*(\.[0-9]{2})?", RegexOptions.Singleline));
```

So the variable 'value' now has, "Value: $1000.00" stored in it.

My question is, using Regex is there a way to use 'Value:' to find the number value but only store the actual number value (i.e. 1000.00) in the 'value' variable?

Comment: FYI, the `Singleline` option isn't doing anything for you.  It allows the `.` *metacharacter* to match linefeeds, but the only place the dot appears in your regex, it's escaped in order to match a *literal* `.`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, to accomplish something like this, you have at least 3 options:

- Use lookarounds `(?=...)`, `(?<=...)`, so you can match precisely what you want to capture

  - Some languages have limited support for lookbehinds
- Use capturing group `(...)` to capture specific strings

  - Near universally supported in all flavors
- You can also just take a `substring` of the match

  - Works well if the length of the prefix/suffix to chop is a known constant

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and [Groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

---

#### Examples

Given this test string:

```
i have 35 dogs, 16 cats and 10 elephants
```

These are the matches of some regex patterns:

- `\d+ cats` -> `16 cats` ([see on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/UEEwAf6zjQ))
- `\d+(?= cats)` -> `16` ([see on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/gkm77p7OFU))
- `(\d+) cats` -> `16 cats` ([see on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/Ey6wrLYXNw))

  - Group 1 captures `16`

You can also do multiple captures, for example:

- `(\d+) (cats|dogs)` yields 2 match results ([see on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/b4AIq5CxQP))

  - Result 1: `35 dogs`

    - Group 1 captures `35`
    - Group 2 captures `dogs`
  - Result 2: `16 cats`

    - Group 1 captures `16`
    - Group 2 captures `cats`

---

#### Solution for this specific problem

It's much simpler to use capturing group in this case ([see on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/PnUJ5)):

```
var text = "Blah blah Value: $1000.00 and more stuff";
string value = Convert.ToString(
   Regex.Match(
     text,
     @"Value:[ \t]*\$?(\d*(\.[0-9]{2})?)",
     RegexOptions.Singleline
   ).Groups[1]
);
```

The only thing that was added was:

- A pair of matching parantheses in the pattern to capture the numeric portion
- Accessing `.Groups[1]` of the `Match` object

Comment: \d+(?= cats) -> 16 That is the one I would like to use, but how do I change my regex to work the way that one does? I have tried this, @"(?=Value:[ \t]*\$?)\d*(\.[0-9]{2})?"

Comment: @Axilus: since `Value: ` is a prefix in this case, you use lookbehind `(?<=...)` instead of lookahead. It is conventional to just use capturing group in these cases, though. Lookarounds are kind of overkill here.

Answer (score 2):

In .NET, you'll want to get the Match object and then access its Groups property:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(BodyContent, @"Value:[ \t]*\$?(?<amount>\d*(\.[0-9]{2})?)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
string value = null;

if (m.Success)
{
    value = m.Groups["amount"].Value;
}
```

The syntax `(?<amount> ... )` creates a named capture group that is stored by name in the m.Groups collection.